# Graph API - can't create a Online meeting from Microsoft personal account

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365api, outlook-restapi, microsoft-graph-teams

I tried to schedule a online meeting using [create event api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-4-create-and-enable-an-event-as-an-online-meeting) from personal account. The online meeting is created as a normal calendar events. ***When I tried to schedule a online meeting from Teams UI, It was working.***

Am I missed any mandatory key in the request body ?

**Body**

```
{
"isOnlineMeeting": true,
"subject": "Test",
"attendees": [
    {
        "emailAddress": {
            "address": "",
            "name": ""
        }
    }
],
"start": {
    "dateTime": "2022-12-25T20:00:00",
    "timeZone": "Etc/GMT"
},
"onlineMeetingProvider": "teamsForBusiness",
"end": {
    "dateTime": "2022-12-25T20:10:00",
    "timeZone": "Etc/GMT"
},
"body": {
    "contentType": "Text",
    "content": "Online meeting test"
}}
```

**Response from microsoft**

```
{
"@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('')/calendars('ZMvDBjXvwAAAgEGAAAAmqfWg_ObkUyChZMvDBjXvwABT3jSD')/events/$entity",
"@odata.etag": "W/\"mqfWBjSg==\"",
"id": "AZC0zZTkwLTkwOTYtMDACLTAwCgBGAAADMzRR5znaHU6VMrGdn04PGAcAmqfWg_ObkUyChZMvDBjXvwA",
"createdDateTime": "2022-12-26T15:31:19.775368Z",
"lastModifiedDateTime": "2022-12-26T15:31:21.0563805Z",
"changeKey": "jXvwABVl7OSg==",
"categories": [],
"transactionId": null,
"originalStartTimeZone": "Etc/GMT",
"originalEndTimeZone": "Etc/GMT",
"iCalUId": "0000010000000B6C8043BEB745041BED36DFE1F395B35",
"reminderMinutesBeforeStart": 15,
"isReminderOn": true,
"hasAttachments": false,
"subject": "Test",
"bodyPreview": "Online meeting test",
"importance": "normal",
"sensitivity": "normal",
"isAllDay": false,
"isCancelled": false,
"isOrganizer": true,
"responseRequested": true,
"seriesMasterId": null,
"showAs": "busy",
"type": "singleInstance",
"webLink": "https://outlook.live.com/owa/?itemid=BObkUyChZMvDBjXvwABT3ib0AAAAJqn1oPjm5FMgoWTLwwY178AAVZo8bMAAAA%3D&exvsurl=1&path=/calendar/item",
"onlineMeetingUrl": null,
"isOnlineMeeting": false,
"onlineMeetingProvider": "unknown",
"allowNewTimeProposals": true,
"occurrenceId": null,
"isDraft": false,
"hideAttendees": false,
"responseStatus": {
    "response": "organizer",
    "time": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
},
"body": {
    "contentType": "html",
    "content": "<html><head><meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\"><meta name=\"Generator\" content=\"Microsoft Exchange Server\"><!-- converted from text --><style><!-- .EmailQuote { margin-left: 1pt; padding-left: 4pt; border-left: #800000 2px solid; } --></style></head><body><font size=\"2\"><span style=\"font-size:11pt;\"><div class=\"PlainText\">Online meeting test</div></span></font></body></html>"
},
"start": {
    "dateTime": "2022-12-25T20:00:00.0000000",
    "timeZone": "Etc/GMT"
},
"end": {
    "dateTime": "2022-12-25T20:10:00.0000000",
    "timeZone": "Etc/GMT"
},
"location": {
    "displayName": "",
    "locationType": "default",
    "uniqueIdType": "unknown",
    "address": {},
    "coordinates": {}
},
"locations": [],
"recurrence": null,
"attendees": [
    {
        "type": "required",
        "status": {
            "response": "none",
            "time": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        },
        "emailAddress": {
            "name": "",
            "address": ""
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "required",
        "status": {
            "response": "none",
            "time": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        },
        "emailAddress": {
            "name": "",
            "address": ""
        }
    }
],
"organizer": {
    "emailAddress": {
        "name": "",
        "address": ""
    }
},
"onlineMeeting": null}
```

***After schedule a online meeting from Teams***

```
{
        "@odata.etag": "jXvwABVl7Oag==\",
        "id": "fWg_ObkUyChZMvDBjXvwAAAgENAAAAmqfWg_ObkUyChZMvDBjXvwABVmkRAgAAAA==",
        "createdDateTime": "2022-12-26T15:59:36.4206723Z",
        "lastModifiedDateTime": "2022-12-26T16:00:05.0858368Z",
        "changeKey": "jXvwABVl7Oag==",
        "categories": [],
        "transactionId": null,
        "originalStartTimeZone": "India Standard Time",
        "originalEndTimeZone": "India Standard Time",
        "iCalUId": "319D90100000000000000001000000012E42C51A092324F92FC8DCA5BB3C18F",
        "reminderMinutesBeforeStart": 15,
        "isReminderOn": true,
        "hasAttachments": false,
        "subject": "Online meeting test",
        "bodyPreview": "________________________________________________________________________________Microsoft Teams meetingJoin on your computer, mobile app or room deviceClick here to join the meetingLearn more | Meeting options______________________________",
        "importance": "normal",
        "sensitivity": "normal",
        "isAllDay": false,
        "isCancelled": false,
        "isOrganizer": true,
        "responseRequested": true,
        "seriesMasterId": null,
        "showAs": "busy",
        "type": "singleInstance",
        "webLink": "https://outlook.live.com/owa/?itemid=bkUyChZMvDBjXvwAAAgENAAAAmqfWg%2BObkUyChZMvDBjXvwABVmkRAgAAAA%3D%3D&exvsurl=1&path=/calendar/item",
        "onlineMeetingUrl": null,
        "isOnlineMeeting": true,
        "onlineMeetingProvider": "teamsForBusiness",
        "allowNewTimeProposals": true,
        "occurrenceId": null,
        "isDraft": false,
        "hideAttendees": false,
        "responseStatus": {
            "response": "organizer",
            "time": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        },
        "body": {
            "contentType": "html",
            "content": "<html><head><meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\"></head><body><div><br><br><br><div style=\"width:100%; height:20px\"><span style=\"white-space:nowrap; color:#5F5F5F; opacity:.36\">________________________________________________________________________________</span></div><div class=\"me-email-text\" lang=\"\" style=\"color:#252424; font-family:'Segoe UI','Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif\"><div style=\"margin-top:24px; margin-bottom:20px\"><span style=\"font-size:24px; color:#252424\">Microsoft Teams meeting</span></div><div style=\"margin-bottom:20px\"><div style=\"margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; font-weight:bold\"><span style=\"font-size:14px; color:#252424\">Join on your computer, mobile app or room device</span></div><a href=\"https://teams.live.com/meet/9513314047169\" class=\"me-email-headline\" title=\"https://teams.live.com/meet/9513314047169\" style=\"font-size:14px; font-family:'Segoe UI Semibold','Segoe UI','Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; text-decoration:underline; color:#6264a7\">Click here to join the meeting</a> </div><div style=\"margin-bottom:24px; margin-top:20px\"><a href=\"https://aka.ms/JoinTeamsMeeting\" class=\"me-email-link\" title=\"https://aka.ms/jointeamsmeeting\" style=\"font-size:14px; text-decoration:underline; color:#6264a7; font-family:'Segoe UI','Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif\">Learn more</a> | <a href=\"https://teams.live.com/meetingOptions/meetings/9513314047169/view?localeCode=en-GB\" class=\"me-email-link\" title=\"https://teams.live.com/meetingoptions/meetings/9513314047169/view?localecode=en-gb\" style=\"font-size:14px; text-decoration:underline; color:#6264a7; font-family:'Segoe UI','Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif\">Meeting options</a> </div></div><div style=\"font-size:14px; margin-bottom:4px; font-family:'Segoe UI','Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif\"></div><div style=\"font-size:12px\"></div></div><div style=\"width:100%; height:20px\"><span style=\"white-space:nowrap; color:#5F5F5F; opacity:.36\">________________________________________________________________________________</span></div><div></div></body></html>"
        },
        "start": {
            "dateTime": "2022-12-27T12:30:00.0000000",
            "timeZone": "UTC"
        },
        "end": {
            "dateTime": "2022-12-27T13:00:00.0000000",
            "timeZone": "UTC"
        },
        "location": {
            "displayName": "",
            "locationType": "default",
            "uniqueIdType": "unknown",
            "address": {},
            "coordinates": {}
        },
        "locations": [],
        "recurrence": null,
        "attendees": [
            {
                "type": "required",
                "status": {
                    "response": "none",
                    "time": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
                },
                "emailAddress": {
                    "name": "",
                    "address": ""
                }
            }
        ],
        "organizer": {
            "emailAddress": {
                "name": "",
                "address": ""
            }
        },
        "onlineMeeting": {
            "joinUrl": "https://teams.live.com/meet/47169"
        },
        "calendar@odata.associationLink": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users('')/calendars('04PGAcAmqfWg_ObkUyChZMvDBjXvwAAAgEGAAAAmqfWg_ObkUyChZMvDBjXvwAAAiczAAAA')/$ref",
        "calendar@odata.navigationLink": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users('')/calendars('04PGAcAmqfWg_ObkUyChZMvDBjXvwAAAgEGAAAAmqfWg_ObkUyChZMvDBjXvwAAAiczAAAA')"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I also tried the same from my end , and got the same issue ,you can't use onlineMeetingProvider:"teamsForBusiness" because you are using personal account ,the possible values are unknown, teamsForBusiness, skypeForBusiness, and skypeForConsumer and By default, onlineMeetingProvider is unknown . Graph API is not supported to create teams meeting online for personal account, either you can do through the teams app or go with skype one.

[image]

[image]

You can try by removing "onlineMeetingProvider": "teamsForBusiness" , you will get skype meeting link

[image]

Another way to create teams online meeting - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

But this is not supported with delegated permission for personal microsoft account [image]